# dynamic `FramelLabel` and `Legend`

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, frame

How to create a dynamic `FramelLabel` and dynamic `Legend` for various parameter **y1**?   ( for the commands `Plot`,  `Plot3D` or `Show` )

```
y1 = 1;  
f1[x_, y_] = x^2 y 
p1 = Plot[f1[x, y1], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel ->   {{"f1[x,y1]", ""}, {x, ""}}]
```

For example,
when
`y1 = 1`,
the outcome for dynamical FrameLabel will be as follows:
[image]

when

```
y1 = 2;

f2[x_, y_] = x^3 y
```

the outcome for dynamical legends will be as follows:
[image]

**My Goal:** I want to automatize that when I change variable `y1`,
`legend` and `Framelabel` in Plots automatically will be changed

Comment: Could you explain a bit about your desired outcome? plotting with multiple `y1` or using `Manipulate` or ...

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're asking is `Manipulate`:

```
f1[x_, y_] = x^2 y
Manipulate[
 Plot[f1[x, y1], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {{"f1[x," <> ToString[y1] <> "]", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotLabel -> "y1=" <> ToString[y1]], {y1, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Result:

[image]

Also, you can plot multiple functions at the same time just like your second image, check out [Manipulate Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).

Comment: Thank you.  What is the difference between `<> ToString[y1] <>` and `<> ToString[y1]`. I am quite new in Mathematica.

Comment: @1_student `<>` is used for concatenating strings, the main function is `StringJoin` but `<>` is easier to use. I used `<> ToString[y1] <>` to add some string before and after `y1` value but with `<> ToString[y1]` you can't add string after the `y1` value. `"f1[x," <> ToString[y1] <> "]"` is the equivalent to `StringJoin["f1[x,",ToString[y1] , "]"]`.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

```
y1 = 2;
f1[x_, y_] = x^2 y
p1 = Dynamic@
  Plot[Evaluate[f1[x, y1]], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{Dynamic[f[x, y]], ""}, {x, ""}}]
```

[image]

If you now change y1:

```
y1 = 10;
```

[image]

or if you change the function f1:

```
y1 = 2;
f1[x_, y_] = x^(1/2) y
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
y1 = 1;
f1[x_, y_] = x^2 y
p1 = Plot[f1[x, y1], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"f1[x," <> ToString[Evaluate[y1]] <> "]", ""}, {x, 
     ""}}]
```

[image: output of the evaluated ToString converted constant]

Comment: Is `Evaluate` necessary in the `f1[x," <> ToString[Evaluate[y1]] <> "]`.  I think that `f1[x," <> ToString[y1] <> "]` runs, too ?

Comment: Depends. If like in the question `y1` is assigned a value in exactly the presented way. This is [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html). In the section Different kind of values there are example to  be considered, scoping, if the parameter is in need to be function of some kind. To use Evaluate in this in general is somewhat a safe wrapper but not necessary to get results in all cases. This is a tricky question in Mathematica. Try a fresh variable assign, then reuse. Hold, [Unevaluated](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html?q=Unevaluated) differences.

Comment: Thank you for all.

Comment: @1_student `Evaluate` does nothing here. It would _only_ do something if `ToString` had a `Hold` attribute, which of course it doesn't. It _only_ looks at the function that wraps it directly. I honestly can't understand what Steffen is trying to say with that comment, but either he's saying nothing or he's saying something incorrect.